# Find a convex function which is not strictly convex but strictly quasiconvex.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

It is relatively easy to find a convex function which is not strictly convex. Take $f(x) = C$ is a constant for example. But I get stuck on finding a convex function which is not strictly convex BUT is strictly quasiconvex.

Can anyone give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, for any convex function the inequalities $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x) +(1-t)f(y)\leq max(f(x), f(y)) $ holds where the last is strict iff $f(x) \neq f(y) $ so your function would have to be injective, but somehow I can't picture a convex function being injective...

Comment: OK, here is my hint, look for a convex, but not strictly convex function which is also injective. Think very simple.

Comment: @ManateePink Thanks for your hint. I am still trying to find a specific function satisfying that...

Comment: Well, is there a function where for all $x, y \in dom(f), x\neq y, t\in(0,1): f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x) +(1-t)f(y)<max(f(x),f(y))$?

Comment: @ManateePink I think $f(x) \equiv x$ should satisfy this property.

Comment: There you go then, right? The identity function on some intervall of the real numbers is convex, but not strictly convex and strictly quasiconvex.

Comment: @ManateePink Got! Thanks so much!